# Aplicar filtro en tablas relacionadas laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

La version de laravel es la 5.4

Aqui pongo el link del proyecto para descargar (Incluye base de datos para importar. Esta en App/filtros_laravel.sql)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/or78bfgg71xmlmp/filtros.zip?dl=0

Voy a dar una descripcion del problema. Primero empecemos con las tablas.

```
 create table clientes
    (
        idcliente int primary KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        nombre varchar(35) not null,
        telefono varchar(30) null

    );

    create table pagos
    (
        idpago int primary KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        nombre_pago varchar(35) not null,
        idcliente int not null,
        idestado int not null

    );

    CREATE TABLE estado_pagos
    (
        idestado int primary KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        nombre_pago varchar(30) not null
    );

    ALTER TABLE pagos ADD FOREIGN KEY(idcliente)  REFERENCES clientes(idcliente);
    ALTER TABLE pagos ADD FOREIGN KEY(idestado)  REFERENCES estado_pagos(idestado);
```

Básicamente dice que un cliente tiene muchos pagos. Un pago pertenece a un estado_pago(pendiente, pagado).
Ejemplo:

```
idcliente:1
nombre:Carlos
telefono: 391929
Pagos de carlos: 
idpago:1,nombre_pago:pago1,idcliente:1,idestado:1,nombre_pago:Pendiente
idpago:2,nombre_pago:pago2,idcliente:1,idestado:1,nombre_pago:Pendiente
idpago:3,nombre_pago:pago3,idcliente:1,idestado:3,nombre_pago:Pagado

idcliente:2
nombre:Juliana
telefono: 122222
Pagos: 
idpago:4,nombre_pago:pago julio,idcliente:1,idestado:1,nombre_pago:pendiente
idpago:5,nombre_pago:pago agosto,idcliente:1,idestado:3,nombre_pago:pagado
idpago:6,nombre_pago:pago promociones,idcliente:1,idestado:3,nombre_pago:pagado



tabla estados
idestado:1
nombre_pago:Pendiente

idestado:2
nombre_pago:No valido

idestado:3
nombre_pago:Pagado
```

Necesito que me traiga el cliente con todos sus pagos con estado pagado. Osea que no debe de traer los clientes con estado de pago pendiente. Solo los pagados. osea que debe de traerlo asi

```
idcliente:1
nombre:Carlos
telefono: 391929
Pagos: 
idpago:3,nombre_pago:pago1,idcliente:1,idestado:3,nombre_pago:Pagado

idcliente:2
nombre:Juliana
telefono: 122222
Pagos: 
idpago:2,nombre_pago:pago1,idcliente:1,idestado:3,nombre_pago:Pagado
idpago:3,nombre_pago:pago1,idcliente:1,idestado:3,nombre_pago:Pagado
```

Los modelos en laravel estan asi

Modelo Clientes

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cliente extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'clientes';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idcliente';
    public $timestamps = false;


    public function pagos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Pago', 'idcliente');
    }
}
```

Modelo Pagos

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pago extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pagos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idpago';
    public $timestamps = false;


    public function cliente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Cliente', 'idcliente');
    }


    public function estado()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\EstadoPago', 'idestado');
    }

}
```

Modelo estado_pagos

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EstadoPago extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'estado_pagos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idestado';
    public $timestamps = false;


    public function pagos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Pago', 'idestado');
    }
}
```

El controlador esta asi

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Cliente;
use App\Pago;
use App\EstadoPago;

class ClienteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       $clientes = cliente::with('pagos.estado')->whereHas('pagos.estado', function ($query) {
        $query->where('nombre_pago', '=', 'pagado');
        })->get();

       return json_encode($clientes);
    }

}
```

Como hago ese filtro ? Estoy tratando con Eloquent. He intentado con whereHas y "with" No funciona ninguno de los dos.
El whereHas no me funciona. Me sigue mostrando todos los pagos con estado pendiente y pagado. Solo quiero que me muestre los pagos con estado pagados como mencione en el ejemplo anterior. Debe de ser como esta en el ejemplo. 
Esto: `whereHas('pagos.estado')` Simplemente va al modelo Cliente, despues va al Modelo Pago y despues va al modelo Estado_pago. Luego esto filtra en Estado_pago
 `$query->where('nombre_pago', '=', 'pagado');` pero no funciona como puedo hacer ese filtro? es con whereHas o con otro porque no me funciona tampoco con el with.

```
public function index()
    {
       $clientes = cliente::with('pagos.estado')->with(['pagos.estado' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('nombre_pago', '=', 'pagado');
        }])->get();

       return json_encode($clientes);
    }
```

Lo estoy retornando en un json porque así veo mejor los datos. El resultado del json lo miro en esta pagina

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Veo el cliente con sus pagos y estado de pago. Todo en un mismo objeto.

eso me lo muestra en un objeto. para entenderlo mucho mas claro.

Necesito realizar filtros de esta manera. Esto se puede hacer filtrando por idestado = 3, pero eso no es lo que necesito. El filtro se realiza es por el nombre. Esto es debido a que tengo consultas de este tipo , filtro a otras tablas. El filtro no puedo hacerlo por id. Quiero y necesito por nombre.
Ayuda por favor en esto. He buscado mucho en videos , stackoverflow y otras partes. En ingles y espanol y no encuentro nada. De verdad que me he esforzado mucho. Me esforce mucho para poner esta pregunta muy detallada y clara. Estoy bloqueado con esto de verdad ayuda. Con join se puede hacer pero eso no es lo que estoy buscando. Solo estoy buscando filtro con eloquent. Nada de join.

Comment: me extraña que laravel en eloquent, (una gran utilidad como dicen muchos por ahi aunque no les he visto utilizarlo de verdad en consultas) no tenga solucion para algo asi, es una consulta sencilla con un filtro sencillo, veo que muchos hablan de eloquent. Por favor pido probar el codigo antes de dar la solucion , porque les aseguro que en la primera solucion que piensen no les va a funcionar, he probado varios intentos.

Comment: este codigo Cliente::whereHas('pagos.estado', function ($query) {
    $query->where('nombre_pago', 'pagado');
})->get(); solo trae los clientes pero no me trae los pagos con los estados esto se puede verificar como mencione anteriormente en http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/  por eso recalco que la primera solucion que piensen seguramente no va a funcionar porque yo necesito que traiga los pagos con estado pagado , por favor verificar en http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ que este dando cliente con pagos y con estado_pagos aqui se puede comprobar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YyEUlvom8o0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno, aunque lo que quieres hacer puede ser un poco particular y extremo desde el punto de vista de la forma como funciona Laravel y las relaciones que funcionan como propiedades dinámicas, aquí tienes la solución:

```
Cliente::with(['pagos' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('estado', function ($query) { 
            $query->where('nombre_pago', 'pagado');
        });
    },
    'pagos.estado' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('nombre_pago', 'pagado');
    }])
    ->whereHas('pagos.estado', function ($query) {
        $query->where('nombre_pago', 'pagado');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Cliente::whereHas('pagos', function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('estado', function ($query) {
        $query->where('nombre_pago', 'pagado');
    });
})->get(); no funciona. Eso es el equivalente al whereHas que puse osea whereHas(pagos.estado) ...

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda. Ese codigo no funciona porque solo trae los clientes pero no trae los pagos y estados de pago que es lo que necesito. aqui en este link lo puedes comprobar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YyEUlvom8o0  es por eso que utilizo el with. Aqui se puede verificar en el json http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ como es que arroja los resultados por favor verificar que arroje todo con cliente y pago

Comment: Ya logré entender que es lo que quieres. Más tarde lo reviso.

Comment: Dale muchas gracias. Quedo completamente atento. Eso me esta volviendo loco

Comment: He encontrado lo que querías, revisa la edición de mi respuesta.

Comment: Increible. Con razon no pude resolverla. Eso involucraba hacer esa combinación. Eso era exactamente lo que queria y ya la acepte como respuesta en este foro. Caso cerrado. Creia que no se podia hacer. Muchas gracias. No tengo nada mas que decir muy bien.